# Need help linking image with File Pathways

Tags: html

I'm having trouble getting some images to show. The issue starts at C:\Users... and ends at .\august19\google2.0.0.jpg

I'm not very experienced with the ... thing in pathways

I've tried  but it doesn't work. A large space appears but image doesn't show

```
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <title>My First Webpage</title>

</head>

<body>

<p style="background-color: blue; color: white">
        My First Paragraph <br>
        My second sentence in this paragraph on another line
</p>

<p style="background-color: green; color: white"> My Second Paragraph >:3c</p>

C:\Users\sierr\OneDrive\Documents\html practice due tuesday\images\google2.0.0.jpg
https://www.google.com/images/google2.0.0.jpg

.\images\google2.0.0.jpg"
.\august19\google2.0.0.jpg"

<a href="https://www.apple.com">
         <img src="images/23656.png" width=500 border=0 />
</a>

<a href="/html5Template.html">Home</a>
<a href="/august19/august19.html">August19</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to put your `.jpg` path into an `<img>` tag. i.e. `<img src="C:\Users\sierr\OneDrive\Documents\html practice due tuesday\images\google2.0.0.jpg
https://www.google.com/images/google2.0.0.jpg">`

Answer (score 0):

In order for the browser to render the image, you need to put it in an `<img>` tag.

```
<img src="C:\Users\sierr\OneDrive\Documents\html practice due tuesday\images\google2.0.0.jpg https://www.google.com/images/google2.0.0.jpg">
```